# Segmentation fault when creating a tree (C)

Tags: c

I really don't understand why I am seg faulting here. This is the most simple code ever.

So basically, I have this simple node struct

```
struct node {
    int value;
    struct node *left_child;
    struct node *right_child;
};
```

and when I test this node struct like this:

```
struct node *m_node;
m_node->value = 10;
printf("%d\n", m_node->value);
```

Everything works fine here.

Now, with this simple tree struct, things start breaking.

```
struct tree {
    int size;
    struct node *head;
};
```

I try testing it like this:

```
struct tree *m_tree;
m_tree->head = m_node;
printf("%d\n", m_tree->head->value);
```

And I get a seg fault. Any ideas?

Comment: You forgot to allocate memory.

Comment: Pointers by default doesn't point anywhere. You must explicitly make them point somewhere valid. I suggest you find some good beginners books to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've created a dangling pointer. Either `malloc()` a space, or assign it to address of a struct that's already created:

```
struct tree *m_tree=malloc(sizeof(struct tree)); // Either this
struct tree *m_tree=&some_node;                  // Or this
```

Comment: Oh yeah. I completely forgot about this coming from c++

Comment: So why don't I need to do this for my node struct?

Comment: You need to do that. If your code is same as what's been posted, it will give the segfalt with node struct too.

Answer (score 0):

When you dereference a pointer that doesn't have a valid pointer value, you produce undefined behaviour. Valid pointer values are values returned by memory allocation functions like `malloc()` and the addresses of other objects obtained by use of the address-of operator `&`.

```
#include <stdlib.h>  // malloc()

// ...

struct node *m_node = malloc(sizeof(*m_node));
m_node->value = 10;
printf("%d\n", m_node->value);

struct tree *m_tree = malloc(sizeof(*m_tree));
m_tree->head = m_node;
printf("%d\n", m_tree->head->value);
```